# text is shortened in variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, echo, quotes, truncate

I created the following file called `birthday`, which contains the following strings:

```
Happy Birthday
Happy Birthday
Happy Birthday
```

when I use the command `cat birthday` the shell will output the text string with the line spacing

```
Happy Birthday
Happy Birthday
Happy Birthday
```

when I try to declare a variable like this - and echo it back everything is truncated on a single string.  How do I keep the spacing and pass it to a variable:

```
birthday=$(cat birthday)  && echo $birthday
```

Output:

```
happy birthday happy birthday happy birthday
```

Comment: use quotes: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without quotes, the shell expands the variable and performs word splitting. Thus, it sends 6 parameters to `echo`, which prints them all separated by spaces.

Use double quotes to prevent word splitting.

```
echo "$birthday"
```

BTW, "truncating" usually describes shortening data by removing bytes at the end, not at random positions inside the data.